# Azure Application Insights Alerts work only once

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am testing Azure Application Insights alert functionality.  It seems to be either buggy or I don't know how to use it.

If I create a new alert, based on the metric 'Server Exceptions', it seems to work once then never again.  Once it fires, it seems to go into a state of 'Active' where there is an orange triangle with an !.  See the image below.  I created a new one, that I haven't triggered, and as can be seen in the image it has a green circle with a tick.

This sort of implies to me that an alert won't fire again until one 'acknowledges' the alert, which is not a bad idea, but I can't see how to do that.

[image]

Edit :

I have just tried to use the 'Exception Rate' as suggested, but I think the minimum threshold to fire the alert would be an average of 1 exception per second over a 5 minute period.

I must say it seems strange that my use-case isn't handled.  I have a light weight Web API service that is so simple it should never fail but it could, and as a result if an exception occurs I want to receive an alert straight away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alert is supposed to resolve and state is supposed to get back to green when the condition of the alert is no longer fulfilled.
This is exceptionally hard to achieve with "Count" metrics because they go up and up and almost never down. It means that, once fired, the alert won't resolve because the value of the metric stays over the threshold all the time.

You can try to set an alert on the "Rate" metric instead and you should see that the state is returning to green when the "Rate" is within the limits you set.

Comment: I'd like to add that new alert rule looks at the "flowing/current" data, not over the "existing/historical" data. In the sample with the exceptions you provided, I assume that there was no new exception after the last alert rule was created, so it stayed green up until the next exception has been detected in the incoming data.

Comment: Yes, the last alert hasn't ever fired.  It is in a test environment, so the exceptions are deterministic (I deliberately cause them to test the alerting).

Even now, almost 24 hours after the last exception, the 3 alerts that have fired are still in the orange / active state.

Comment: I have the Period = "Over the last 5 minutes" selected. As mentioned above, I have waited 24 hours and the alerts haven't cleared.

Comment: It fits the behavior I explained above, alert will be cleared only if count of exceptions goes back under the threshold and it never does because count only increases over the time. "Over 5 minutes" is of no help here because it's just the aggregation period to use for the rule, so if you aggregate a constant count over 5 minutes, you'll still get the same value and alert is not going to be closed. I would suggest to use exceptions/sec here or something similar - it will fire and it will resolve back as soon as rate of errors drops.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that is the only way.  However it doesn't suit my simple use-case, where if a single exception occurs I want an alert.  I am abandoning Insights for my alerting, it doesn't fit my needs, I am just going to wire up my own mechanism.

Comment: @DmitryMatveev: I tried to use "Exception rate" but it shows just "No available data". If I select "Server exceptions" then the alert shows the data but this one does not work because of the "Count" behavior. What could I do?

Comment: Exception Rate metric doesn't seem as reliable for detecting 1 Exception over any 5 minute window. Looked like the runtime kept documenting a bunch of "0.2/s" etc, and spamming emails - even tho no Failure or Exception could be seen in the Function App's monitoring logs. (random noise from the runtime?)

Answer (score 3):

This is now fixed. Please let us know if you see any issues. Some things to keep in mind:

- Alert rules are evaluated on a sliding window: an alert would trigger/resolve based on how the condition evaluates on a sliding window from the instant a sample arrives.
- A caveat to the above for exception count based alert rules:  we will resolve an alert if there are no exceptions reported for the time window configured in the rule.
- Note: this is different from metrics based rules – lack of data does not result in the alert being resolved for those.

Comment: I haven't tested it exhaustively, but it does appear to be working now.  I know that because a number of alerts that I previously created that weren't alerting me suddenly sprang to life the other day.  I had already moved on and written my own alerting mechanism for single exceptions, so I won't actually use this capability in the short term, but its good to know.

Comment: I just can't seem to get this to work myself.
I have posted a question over on the AI forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e678d0a-daf1-49d2-b762-5ece1d44d05e/how-to-alert-on-a-server-exception-in-the-last-5-minutes

Comment: What do you mean for "exception count based alert rules" -- Do you mean "Exception rate"? My experience with Exception rate to solve this, is that it kept registering "random" exceptions in the App Insights metrics that did not seem real/correlate to errors in my Function App. So it started spamming emails about 0.2/s exception rate, even tho I configured threshold as 1 per second in any 5 minute window. It was unreliable

Comment: @user381624 - what Metric exactly were you working against where it started working? "exception count based alert rules" could be "Server Exceptions", "Exception Rate", or ?

Comment: **Metric to use: "Server Exceptions"** You never actually said the metric... that has this helpful behavior. Seemed like you were referring to a different one than OP.

Answer (score 1):

### "Server exception" metric works as OP expects now in 2018. My use case below:

`For the goal of getting an email whenever an Exception happened.`

Use "Server exception" metric.

That metric is smart enough to auto-resolve after waiting the period's length of time after the initial alert, if the error has not occurred again.

So you'll have the initial "Alert", then 5 minutes later of no Exceptions, it returns a "Healthy" state.

And since it auto-resolved, if the error happens again tomorrow it will do the "Alert" again.

---

Note this was using App Insights with a Function App. The Function App Failure metric had problems and wasn't reliable for this (Azure kept logging 0.2 Exception/s and thinking that was over the 1 in 5 min threshold...)