# Application Insights: Define an email alert for every reported crash

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, desktop, azure-application-insights

I have set up an Application Insights service in Azure for a WPF desktop application. The metrics are reported and everything looks right.

*Note: The AI application type is set to: Windows Store Application.*

Now I would like to define an email alert that reports me about every tracked crash. I have added an alert rule:

- Metric: Server exceptions
- Condition: greater than or equal to
- Thershold: 1
- Period: Over the last 5 minutes
- email service and co-administrators: checked
- additional adaministrator email: my email address which is the same as of my Azure account.

In the Alert rules list it shows Last Active with Never. But in the metrics diagram of the alert I see that the crashes are tracked.

How can I get Application Insights to send me an email when a crash is reported?

**Update:** 
The [Azure Application Insights Alerts work only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128944/azure-application-insights-alerts-work-only-once) question is similar than mine but it does not solve my use case. The answer of this question proposes the usage of a ".. Rate" metrics. There is an "Exception rate" metrics which stays in my case always at zero although exceptions are tracked by Application Insights. So my alert does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure Application Insights Alerts work only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128944/azure-application-insights-alerts-work-only-once)

Comment: Looks like this works now just like you're hoping https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303020/1985648

Answer (score 1):

This stackoverflow question/answer provides an explanation why it does not work: 
[Azure Application Insights Alerts work only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128944/azure-application-insights-alerts-work-only-once)

Unfortunately, it does not provide a solution for my use case. Maybe it is just not supported by Application Insights.

Comment: It wasn't, but apparently now it is (according to the other question)

Comment: @MarkSowul - yep it works now. The "Server exceptions" metric is smart enough now to know when it has not received exceptions in the period/time-frame, and then considers it resolved. So the next time it happens it changes state to "Active" and sends the alert as wanted. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303020/1985648

Answer (score 1):

You could now do this using something like Microsoft Flow,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-automate-with-flow

which has ways to query AI resources and then send mails.