# Custom Metric Alerts in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have created a custom metric and created an alert on that with threshold value as 1. I want that every time , I send a different value for this metric, it should trigger the alert, if new value is greater than threshold value. but it trigger the alert only once as next time , alert state is already "Activated". How can I workaround this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Application Insights Alerts work only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128944/azure-application-insights-alerts-work-only-once)

Comment: How did you create that alert? I haven't been able to create such an alert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803020/cant-create-an-alert-for-an-app-insights-custom-metric-on-azure

Answer (score 0):

Alerts only fire when a state *changes*

so if the alert is for `x > 10`, the alert will fire once x becomes 10, and will not be resolved until `x <= 10`.

note: a lack of data does not constitute a state change.

```
telemetry.TrackMetric(x, 11); // causes alert to fire
// 12 hours pass, alert is "active" the entire time
something.wait(12hours);
telemetry.TrackMetric(x, 1); // causes alert to be resolved.
```

and once an alert is active, more values that would cause it to be active do not cause more alerts.

```
telemetry.TrackMetric(x, 11); // causes alert to fire
telemetry.TrackMetric(x, 12); // will NOT cause alert, x is already > 10
telemetry.TrackMetric(x, 13); // will NOT cause alert, x is already > 10
telemetry.TrackMetric(x, 14); // will NOT cause alert, x is already > 10
telemetry.TrackMetric(x, 15); // will NOT cause alert, x is already > 10
telemetry.TrackMetric(x, 16); // will NOT cause alert, x is already > 10
```